# Is 0 a singular point for xy" + sin(x)y = 0?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My friend and I are confused about this one, some people online say it is and some say it isn't does anyone have a definitive answer that they can explain?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a singular point, the coefficient of the leading coefficient has a zero at $x=0$. The resulting trivial equation $0=0$ does not contain the second derivative.

If you divide by $x$, then the modified, not equivalent, equation
$$
y''+\frac{\sin x}{x}y=0
$$
is not defined at $x=0$.

One can remove the definition gap for $\sin\!c(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ using its limit at $x=0$, setting $\sin\!c(0)=1$. The resulting twice modifie DE
$$
y''+\sin\!c(x)y=0
$$
has now continuous coefficients and is thus regular everywhere. At the end it was a removable singularity.